# drupal delete unused module

Tags: mysql, drupal, module

I have a mass of stuff I downloaded during development, a lot of of modules, and now my directory is about 50-60 modules and some of them are disabled and also did some junk in the db, there is a table that related to them or new tables that the module created. Is there a script that can delete the unused modules folder / delete and also clean up unused tables? I searched for that I found nothing...

I'm using d6.

Answer (score 3):

No, as far as I know there is no module/script to do it automatically, however here's what you can do:

- Go to `admin/build/modules`
- Click the uninstall tab at the top of the page
- Select modules to be uninstalled and proceed

Note that not every module has uninstall functions.
All you have to do next is go to the modules folder and delete the desired modules...

Here you have more details about [uninstalling Drupal modules](http://drupal.org/node/250783)

Comment: yeah but 90% of the modules dont have uninstall so then how can i investigate what fields/tables it used and delete it without doing harm?

Comment: Inside each module folder search for something looked like `{table_name}`. If you find any query with `ALTER`, `CREATE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` the modules might have done something to your database. But the effort and amount of time this will take you would be better spent doing a clean installation...

Comment: but what all about my configuration of views, taxonomy, theme and all the stuff? i need to use features module?

Comment: @amirash, the features module is useful to "copy" the configuration of a development machine to a production one, it might be useful in your case if you have all those modules installed on your development and just want to copy the necessary ones to the prod. machine